# Directional slopes.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The surface given by $z = x^2 - y^2$ is cut by the plane given by $y = 3x$, producing a curve in the plane. Find the slope of this curve at the point $(1,3,-8)$.

In order to solve this problem, I substituted $y$ with $3x$ and get $z = 8x^2$.

My understanding of the slope of this curve is $dz\over dx$.

However, they want me to use the direction vector of $y=3x$, i.e, $<3,-1,0>$ and
take the dot product of this with the gradient evaluated at $(1,3,-8)$.

Can someone explain me when to use the former and when to use the latter ?

Comment: You should have $z=-8x^2$, there.

Comment: Oops, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=-8x^2$ is the projection of the curve to the plane $y=0$. The slope of this projection is in general not the slope of your curve.

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks.